# Trace32:Var.watch window is not displaying variable value updates when debugger is running mode

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

I'm using Trace32 to debug micro controller SPC58NXXX software.

I added variables to Var.watch window and these variables values will be change once I run software.

When I run software with Lauterbach debugger even the variable values are changing the new values are not displaying in Var.watch.

I can see new variable values only when I stop debugger.

Do I need to configure in Trace32 settings for displaying variable value changes in var.watch window when debugger is in running mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell the debugger that you want it to update variable values while the processor runs. There are three methods:

1. %E in Var.* windows: `Var.View %E myVar`
2. Access class E: for addresses: `Data.dump E:0x40070000`
3. Global enable (not recommended): `SYStem.Option.DUALPORT ON`

Comment: Hi Reinhard
Thanks for answer
Once I enable dual port it works